# how does an OPTIONS request get handled if `preFlightContinue` is used

Tags: node.js, express, http, cors, preflight

I realized I don't fully understand how an "preflight OPTIONS request" is handled by Express, this is a standard setting:

```
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
  preflightContinue: true  // here
}));
```

I have 3 questions:

1. what exactly is the difference between `preflightContinue: true` and `preflightContinue: false`
2. Which is the default express setting? - my guess is the flag defaulted to `false`
3. Most importantly: with `preflightContinue: true`, *when/how* does the OPTIONS request get responded to? Is it magically responded to with the normal request?

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/cors/issues/153

Comment: By standard setting, did you mean a setting that people frequently use, or just that it's a setting that exists. I don't see a reason people would frequently use this setting other than by copying and pasting code they don't understand. (a frequent occurrence with CORS errors)

Comment: @KevinB I mean a very common configuration

Comment: @HeikoTheißen if you want to add that as an answer, with an example, I will upvote thanks

Comment: I believe that this `preflightContinue` feature is only useful because the middleware incorrectly assumes that an `OPTIONS` request automatically is a preflight request. [Clearly](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-request), that is not quite right. I've written about such misclassification of `OPTIONS` requests in [a recent blog post](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#4-categorise-requests-correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option allows you to manufacture a response to preflight requests with your own middleware after the necessary headers have been set. See the [source code](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/f038e7722838fd83935674aa8c5bf452766741fb/lib/index.js#L163-L182).

A (completely artificial) example for this would be setting a non-standard header in preflight responses, like here:

```js
app.use(cors({preflightContinue: true}))
.options("*", function(req, res) {
  res.set("X-Preflight-Response", "true").end();
});
```

A better reason why this option is needed can be found in https://github.com/expressjs/cors/issues/305#issuecomment-1761041281.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you get that use case for `preflightContinue`? Is that something you need yourself?

Comment: No, I just took inspiration from the comment in the source code.

Comment: Are you referring to the comment about Safari and response status codes? No need for the `preflightContinue` option for that; instead, you can set the `optionsSuccessStatus` property to your desired status code.

Comment: The `Content-Length` header is probably the better example.

Comment: But... this concern (only a real one for some really old browsers anyway) is already [taken care of in the `else` branch](https://github.com/expressjs/cors/blob/f038e7722838fd83935674aa8c5bf452766741fb/lib/index.js#L179), i.e. when `preflightContinue` is _disabled_. So no offense, but I don't understand how your updated use case is a good one either.  I think a better explanation for the need for a `preflightContinue` option in Express's CORS middleware library can be found in https://github.com/expressjs/cors/issues/305#issuecomment-1761041281

Comment: I like your latest update (+1), even though I'm still not sure if cases exist in which it would be useful.